# Gmail not loading when script is injected or even when a word is replaced, why?

Tags: javascript, proxy, fiddler, javascript-injection

I was using fiddler core proxy to do some script injection. I noticed that gmail login just failed after its login progress bar moving forward and backward for some time. A sample is given below using c#, tested using google chrome as the browser. The below code goes inside the beforeresponse event of fiddler proxy where oS is the HTTP session.

```
  oS.utilDecodeResponse();
  oS.utilReplaceInResponse("</body>", "<script type='text/javascript'>var a = 10;</script></body>");
```

**Updated**

As Eric have suggested I made sure that the script is not making conflict with any other java script variables. Added the script only in the expected page when gmail logs in. However the problem is still there.

```
                if (oS.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod == "GET" || oS.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod == "POST")
                {  //exclude other HTTP Status codes
                    if (oS.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseStatus == "200 OK")
                    {
                        if (!oS.oRequest.headers.Exists("X-Requested-With"))
                        {
                            var accept = oS.oRequest.headers.FindAll("Accept");
                            if (accept[0].Value.Contains("text/html"))
                            {
                                if (oS.oResponse.MIMEType == "text/html")
                                {
                                    oS.utilDecodeResponse();



                                    string script = "alert("Hello");"
                                 //The main http request after gmail login has a response with a script closing tag before body closing, so I am replacing it with my script added.
                                  oS.utilReplaceOnceInResponse("</script></body>", script + "</script></body>", false));



                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Works fine with chrome, however in safari and opera, alert is called infinitely so as the HTTP request to reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your replacement is insufficiently precise. You're replacing ALL instances of `</body>` on ALL pages with a string containing quotation marks. However, in some of the instances, the string you're replacing is appearing within JavaScript strings in the Google application, and as a consequence you're mangling the JavaScript string and causing a script error.

Use the following script sample to get a better understanding of all of the places you're replacing, then update your script to more specifically replace the expected string on only the expected page.

```
    oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
    if (oSession.utilReplaceInResponse("</body>", '<!-- INJECTED --></body>'))
    {            
        oSession["ui-backcolor"] = "lime";
    }
```

Comment: I initially thought gmail is doing some kind of reflection or message hash to check code integrity and to prevent script injection. Because even oS.utilPrependToResponseBody("Hello"); caused the same problem. Thanks and I guess oS.utilReplaceOnceInResponse would work better avoiding multiple injection on same session.

Comment: The problem still exist! I made sure that the script is injected in only one session where the main HTML content is loaded. I am sorry the problem still persist in Opera and Safari. But chrome works fine as expected.

Comment: I don't have any problems injecting here. Be sure to clear your cache between each experiment.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I noticed that my script was also injected inside another giant javascript of gmail, because that javascript code contained </body> string for some reason. This throwed an script error, and in gmail if script error happens the whole page is reloaded by the global error catch statement.